# Highlight selected character dynamically in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to **highlight selected character** in iOS, as you an see in iPhone iOS 7 Notes app.
When you search for particular text the search character will be highlighted in the result displayed in `UITableView`.

Example:

> **"This is my name"**
>
> **h** - should 've blue color
>
> **y** - should 've red color

The character customisation should be dynamic. I hope I've briefed enough.

Looking for excellent response buddies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by setting an **attributed string** to the text label in a `UITableViewCell` that shows an entry of your search results.

You would need to calculate ranges of the substrings that should be highlighted. You can do it using regular expressions as I wrote in my sample code. This way you can support multiple occurrences of the substring in a string.

Then, when you have the ranges you just apply special attributes and set the cell label's `attributedText` property.

The code could look like this:

```
NSString *searchTerm = ...;
NSString *text = @"This is a sample text that is super cool";

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];

NSString *pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)", searchTerm];
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                                                       options:kNilOptions 
                                                                         error:nil];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, text.length);

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:text 
                        options:kNilOptions 
                          range:range 
                     usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, 
                                         NSMatchingFlags flags, 
                                                    BOOL *stop) 
{
    NSRange subStringRange = [result rangeAtIndex:1];

    [attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName 
                             value:[UIColor blueColor] 
                             range:subStringRange];
}];
```

Then it's easy. You just set the `UILabel`'s `attributedText` when creating a cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

This should point you to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Try having a look at TextKit

[This](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/getting-to-know-textkit.html) is a nice website that shows you the basics

I hope I understood your question..

Answer (score 0):

Use NsMutableAttributedString to highlight characters

```
 NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:display];
 [str addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange([displayString length], ([details.notificationCount length]+2))];
displayLabel.attributedText     = str;
```